# Values changes from double to integer when saving to mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring, database, validation, types

Entities:
Simulation:

```
package Simulations.Entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Builder
@Table
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Simulation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "N")
    private String simulation_Name;

    @Column(name = "P")
    private Double population_Size;

    @Column(name = "I")
    private Double initial_Infected_Number;

    @Column(name = "R")
    private Double how_Many_One_Infects;

    @Column(name = "M")
    private Double mortality_Rate;

    @Column(name = "Ti")
    private Double number_Of_Days_To_Recovery;

    @Column(name = "Tm")
    private Double number_Of_Days_To_Death;

    @Column(name = "Ts")
    private Double simulation_Time;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "simulation", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<SimulationsValues> simulationsValues;
}
```

SimulationValues:

```
package Simulations.Entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Builder
@Table
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SimulationsValues {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Day")
    private Double day;

    @Column(name = "Pi")
    private Double number_Of_Infected;

    @Column(name = "Pv")
    private Double healthy_Prone_To_Infection;

    @Column(name = "Pm")
    private Double dead;

    @Column(name = "Pr")
    private Double regained_Health_And_Immunity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "simulation_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Simulation simulation;
}
```

Logic calss:

```
package Simulations.Services;

import Simulations.Entity.Simulation;
import Simulations.Entity.SimulationsValues;
import Simulations.Repositories.SimulationRepository;
import Simulations.Repositories.SimulationsValuesRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
@Aspect
public class EachRemainingDayService {


    private final SimulationRepository simulationRepository;
    private final SimulationsValuesRepository simulationsValuesRepository;


    @Pointcut("@annotation(Simulations.Annotations.MyAnnotation)")
    public void MyAnnotationMethod() {
    }


    public List<Simulation> getSimulations() {
        List<Simulation> listOdIds = new ArrayList<>(simulationRepository.findAll());
        listOdIds.sort(Comparator.comparing(Simulation::getId));
        return listOdIds;
    }

    public List<SimulationsValues> getSimulationsValues() {
        List<SimulationsValues> listOdIdsOfValues = new ArrayList<>(simulationsValuesRepository.findAll());
        listOdIdsOfValues.sort(Comparator.comparing(SimulationsValues::getId));
        return listOdIdsOfValues;
    }


    //3 zapis wynikow do bazy
    @After("MyAnnotationMethod()")// zmienilem z Before
    public void SimulationParametersForRemainingDays() {


        var sim = getSimulations();
        var newestSimulation = simulationRepository.getById(sim.get(sim.size() - 1).getId());

        var simVal = getSimulationsValues();
        var newestSimulationsVal = simulationsValuesRepository
                .getById(simVal.get(simVal.size() - 1).getId());


        //zapisanie do bazy TO LOGIKA!!!
        for (double i = 2; i <= newestSimulation.getSimulation_Time(); i++) {
            if (newestSimulationsVal.getHealthy_Prone_To_Infection() <= 0) {
                break;
            }

            if (i >= newestSimulation.getNumber_Of_Days_To_Death()
                    && i < newestSimulation.getNumber_Of_Days_To_Recovery()) {

                sim = getSimulations();
                newestSimulation = simulationRepository.getById(sim.get(sim.size() - 1).getId());

                simVal = getSimulationsValues();
                newestSimulationsVal = simulationsValuesRepository
                        .getById(simVal.get(simVal.size() - 1).getId());

                SimulationsValues simulation_values;
                Simulation finalNewestSimulation1 = newestSimulation;
                double finalI = i;



                simulation_values = SimulationsValues.builder()
                        .day(i)
                        .healthy_Prone_To_Infection(newestSimulation.getPopulation_Size() -
                                (((newestSimulation.getHow_Many_One_Infects())
                                        * newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected()
                                        + newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected())))


                        .number_Of_Infected((((newestSimulation.getHow_Many_One_Infects())
                                * newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected()
                                + newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected())//L24
                                - (newestSimulation.getMortality_Rate() * (double) ((simulationsValuesRepository
                                .findAll().stream().filter(e -> e.getDay() == finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                        .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Death()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()).get((int) (simulationsValuesRepository.findAll().stream()
                                        .filter(e -> e.getDay() == (finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                                .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Death()))).count() - 1).getNumber_Of_Infected()))))//V24


                        .regained_Health_And_Immunity(0d)// Z24


                        .dead((newestSimulation.getMortality_Rate() * (double) ((simulationsValuesRepository
                                .findAll().stream().filter(e -> e.getDay() == finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                        .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Death()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()).get((int) (simulationsValuesRepository.findAll().stream()
                                        .filter(e -> e.getDay() == (finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                                .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Death()))).count() - 1).getNumber_Of_Infected()))
                                - newestSimulationsVal.getDead())//V24

                        .build();


                var simId = simulationsValuesRepository.save(simulation_values);
                simId.setSimulation(newestSimulation);//dodane
                var simVal2 = newestSimulation.getSimulationsValues();
                simVal2.add(simId);
                newestSimulation.setSimulationsValues(simVal2);
                simulationRepository.save(newestSimulation);

            } else if (i >= newestSimulation.getNumber_Of_Days_To_Recovery()) {

                sim = getSimulations();
                newestSimulation = simulationRepository.getById(sim.get(sim.size() - 1).getId());

                simVal = getSimulationsValues();
                newestSimulationsVal = simulationsValuesRepository
                        .getById(simVal.get(simVal.size() - 1).getId());


                Simulation finalNewestSimulation1 = newestSimulation;
                double finalI = i;
                SimulationsValues simulation_values;


                simulation_values = SimulationsValues.builder()
                        .day(i)
                        .healthy_Prone_To_Infection(newestSimulation.getPopulation_Size() -
                                ((newestSimulation.getHow_Many_One_Infects())
                                        * newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected()))


                        .number_Of_Infected(((newestSimulation.getHow_Many_One_Infects())
                                * newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected()
                                + newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected())//L24

                                - (newestSimulation.getMortality_Rate() * (double) ((simulationsValuesRepository
                                .findAll().stream().filter(e -> e.getDay() == finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                        .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Death()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()).get((int) (simulationsValuesRepository.findAll().stream()
                                        .filter(e -> e.getDay() == (finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                                .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Death()))).count() - 1).getNumber_Of_Infected())//V24

                                - (((1 - newestSimulation.getMortality_Rate()) * (simulationsValuesRepository
                                .findAll().stream().filter(e -> e.getDay() == finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                        .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Recovery()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()).get((int) (simulationsValuesRepository.findAll().stream()
                                        .filter(e -> e.getDay() == finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                                .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Recovery())).count() - 1)
                                .getNumber_Of_Infected()))//Z24
                        ))


                        .regained_Health_And_Immunity((1 - newestSimulation.getMortality_Rate()) *
                                (simulationsValuesRepository.findAll()
                                        .stream().filter(e -> e.getDay() == finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                                .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Recovery()))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()).get((int) (simulationsValuesRepository.findAll()
                                        .stream().filter(e -> e.getDay() == finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                                .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Recovery())).count() - 1)
                                        .getNumber_Of_Infected())// Z24


                        .dead((newestSimulation.getMortality_Rate() * (double) ((simulationsValuesRepository.findAll()
                                .stream().filter(e -> e.getDay() == finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                        .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Death()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()).get((int) (simulationsValuesRepository.findAll().stream()
                                        .filter(e -> e.getDay() == (finalI + 1 - finalNewestSimulation1
                                             .getNumber_Of_Days_To_Death()))).count()1).getNumber_Of_Infected()))
                                - newestSimulationsVal.getDead())//V24

                        .build();


                var simId = simulationsValuesRepository.save(simulation_values);
                simId.setSimulation(newestSimulation);//dodane
                var simVal2 = newestSimulation.getSimulationsValues();
                simVal2.add(simId);
                newestSimulation.setSimulationsValues(simVal2);
                simulationRepository.save(newestSimulation);

            } else if (i == 2) {
                sim = getSimulations();
                newestSimulation = simulationRepository.getById(sim.get(sim.size() - 1).getId());

                simVal = getSimulationsValues();
                newestSimulationsVal = simulationsValuesRepository
                        .getById(simVal.get(simVal.size() - 1).getId());


                SimulationsValues simulation_values;
                simulation_values = SimulationsValues.builder()
                        .day(i)
                        .healthy_Prone_To_Infection(newestSimulationsVal.getHealthy_Prone_To_Infection() -
                                ((newestSimulation.getHow_Many_One_Infects())
                                        * newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected()))
                        .number_Of_Infected((newestSimulation.getHow_Many_One_Infects())
                                * newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected()
                                + newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected())
                        .regained_Health_And_Immunity(0d)
                        .dead(0d)
                        .build();

                var simId2 = simulationsValuesRepository.save(simulation_values);
                simId2.setSimulation(newestSimulation);//dodane
                var simVal2 = newestSimulation.getSimulationsValues();
                simVal2.add(simId2);
                newestSimulation.setSimulationsValues(simVal2);
                simulationRepository.save(newestSimulation);

            } else {
                sim = getSimulations();
                newestSimulation = simulationRepository.getById(sim.get(sim.size() - 1).getId());

                simVal = getSimulationsValues();
                newestSimulationsVal = simulationsValuesRepository
                        .getById(simVal.get(simVal.size() - 1).getId());


                SimulationsValues simulation_values;
                simulation_values = SimulationsValues.builder()
                        .day(i)
                        .healthy_Prone_To_Infection(newestSimulationsVal.getHealthy_Prone_To_Infection() -
                                ((newestSimulation.getHow_Many_One_Infects())
                                        * newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected()))
                        .number_Of_Infected((newestSimulation.getHow_Many_One_Infects())
                                * newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected()
                                + newestSimulationsVal.getNumber_Of_Infected())
                        .regained_Health_And_Immunity(0d)
                        .dead(0d)
                        .build();

                var simId2 = simulationsValuesRepository.save(simulation_values);
                simId2.setSimulation(newestSimulation);//dodane
                var simVal2 = newestSimulation.getSimulationsValues();
                simVal2.add(simId2);
                newestSimulation.setSimulationsValues(simVal2);
                simulationRepository.save(newestSimulation);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
package Simulations.ViewModels;

import Simulations.Annotations.GreaterThan;
import Simulations.Entity.SimulationsValues;
import lombok.*;

import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMax;
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@GreaterThan(message = "field number of days to death can not be equal or bigger than field days to recovery")
public class SimulationViewModel {

    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "field can not be empty")
    private String simulation_Name;

    @NotNull(message = "field can not be empty")
    @DecimalMax("10000000000.0")
    @DecimalMin("0.0")
    private Double population_Size;

    private Double initial_Infected_Number;

    @NotNull(message = "field can not be empty")
    private Double how_Many_One_Infects;

    @NotNull(message = "field can not be empty")
    @DecimalMax("1.0")
    @DecimalMin("0.001")
    private Double mortality_Rate;

    private @NotNull(message = "field can not be empty") @DecimalMin("1.0")
    Double number_Of_Days_To_Recovery;

    private @NotNull(message = "field can not be empty") @DecimalMin("1.0")
    Double number_Of_Days_To_Death;

    private @NotNull(message = "field can not be empty")
    Double simulation_Time;

    List<SimulationsValues> simulationsValues = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Hi, I have a roblem. When I create a simulationValues object (using builder) it's fields have double values as intended but when I save this object to database and look at thoese values in database (MySql) thoese values are presented as Integers i.e. without values after comma, for example when I debug my code I see that "dead" field has in 12 iteration value 0.9 but it is saved to database as 1. Why is that? I don;t do any casting and all I use for this calculations are doubles as well as all fields n SimulationValues class and SimulationViewModel are doubles. Why when saving field changes types?Thanks in advance

Comment: You must understand does the issue is client-side or server-side one. To do this, in MySQL: (1) execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` and ensure that the datatype for  problematic column is not some integer (or decimal with zero or not specified decimal digits amount); (2) enable General Log temporarily and ensure that the value sent to MySQL is not rounded.

Comment: @Akina thanks, most values that should be double are bigint, don't know why, how do I change them to double? Is dropping this table and letting it to be created again enough?

Comment: *most values that should be double are bigint* **Where** they are BIGINT? in the query which is sent from the client to the server? or the column datatype was created as BIGINT? PS. Do you really need in DOUBLE (approximate values) and not in DECIMAL (precise values)?

Comment: @Akina the column type

Comment: @Akina changed fields in entity class and vieModel to BigDecimal and everything works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All columns in MySql were bigint type instead of double as I made them in coresponding entity, changed them to BigDecimal and everything works fine.